# iPhone 6s repaired without disconnecting the battery

Tags: iphone, repair

I replaced the screen on my iPhone (turned off). With the phone still open I turned it on the check screen and it worked. Since it was locked I pressed the home button, and the screen went on and blank again (the phone still open).
I later realised that I did this whole thing with the battery connected. Did I possibly shortcut anything?

After, I took it apart, disconnected battery and put it all back together, but no luck, the phone won’t turn on.

I followed procedure from [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+6s+Screen+Replacement/62900), except for the battery disconnection step.

Can I try anything or I’ve just cooked it?

Cheers

Edit:
I’ve tried the old cracked screen, and that works.

Comment: Is the screen genuine and from Apple?

Comment: Not genuine part, Apple won’t sell parts to public. Replacement screen has warranty though

Comment: I meant was it from an authorized service provider. If the screen isn’t genuine then there’s the problem mostly